# Why is WAMP not working?

Tags: apache-2.2

My WAMP Icon is always yellow. Port 80 is not in use and I don't use Skype. These are the error messages that I get anyway:

```
[Wed Sep 28 19:21:17 2011] [crit] (OS 6)The handle is invalid.  : master_main: create     child process failed. Exiting.
[Wed Sep 28 19:21:47 2011] [notice] Parent: Forcing termination of child process 36 
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:15 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:15 2011] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:15 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3344
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:15 2011] [crit] (OS 10050)A socket operation encountered a dead network.  : alloc_listener: failed to get a socket for (null)
Syntax error on line 46 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/conf/httpd.conf:
Listen setup failed
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:15 2011] [crit] (OS 6)The handle is invalid.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
[Wed Sep 28 19:26:45 2011] [notice] Parent: Forcing termination of child process 36
```

What's wrong with the WAMP application?

Comment: belongs on serverfault.

Comment: What is "wamp"? I think you've used the wrong tag.

Comment: Windows, Apache, MySql, and PHP.

Comment: user should check/confirm what line 46 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/conf/httpd.conf is

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your [**Listen**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) statement is incorrect in your httpd.conf file. Generally it would be of the form

```
Listen 80
```

to mean listen on port 80 on all available IP addresses.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

to listen only on the IP loopback interface and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax error on line 46 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.8/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Listen setup failed

Your httpd.conf file has a syntax error which is preventing Apache from starting.

Post the contents of the file and we can probably better assist.